# Using the JavaScript pug template engine is there an easy way to remove the last comma, period, ect from the end

Tags: javascript, express, pug

Sorry I didn't really know how to word the question. For example I have this piece of code:

```
p #[strong Genre]&nbsp;
    each val in book.genre
        a(href = val.url) #{val.name}
        | ,
```

I would like to easily format a comma in between without the one at the end. I've probably spent way more time than I should have trying to solve this but I'm stubborn.

Comment: Hi @Zero147x, welcome to SO. If you solved the problem you had, on your own, please post that solution in an answer yourself (instead of editing the original post), and mark that new answer as accepted. That way, this question is not showing up anymore in question feeds as 'unanswered'.

Comment: I did just now and it says I am unable to accept my own answer for 2 days. I will when I am able to though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it on my own. This is how I did it:

```
- var i = 1
- length = (book.genre.length)
    each val in book.genre
        a(href = val.url) #{val.name}
        if (i < length)
            | ,
        - i++
```